# Assigning the same ID to two button in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two buttons that I want both to make use of the same ID shown below

```
<button style="margin-top:4px; background-color:#F2F6F7; padding:11px; border:solid 1px grey" id="btn1">
<i class="icon"></i>
```

Is there a way I can use thesame ID to another button in angular

```
<button style="margin-top:4px; background-color:#F2F6F7; padding:11px; border:solid 1px grey" id="btn1">
<i class="icon">share</i>
</button>
```

I know I can do this using ng-change on input field but don't know much on button ID if it is possible.

Comment: No: IDs must be unique. Consider a class name instead.

Comment: ... and stop using inline styles....

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with the same ids in the button? Using unique IDs is the must when it comes to HTML SPECIFICATION, however  using dup ids does give you what you need sometimes. Nevertheless, use of dup class is recommended rather than dup ids.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the browsers will ignore that fact that there are two items with the same ID in the HTML, however it is recommended to keep IDs unique per DOM.

Also, most of the JavaScript functions are written in such a way that searching by ID will return at most one item.

The real question should be "why do you want/need to have the same ID?"

Answer (score 0):

No, the IDs must be unique. This is just how HTML works - as per the [HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-id).